# Retrieve Build Environment info from Jenkins Scriptler with Groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-scriptler

Is there any workaround that I can retrieve the Build Environment settings for every job in a groovy script ? 
For example I installed the 'Scriptler plugin' and the 'EnvInject plugin' and I want to find out for every job that I have if "manage exclusion" is ticked or not :

[image]

what I did is:

```
println String.format( "<b>List of JOBS :</b>" )`
println ''

for(item in jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(hudson.model.Job.class)) 
{
  if(item instanceof hudson.model.ExternalJob)
    continue  

  println''

  for (env in item.builders)
    println env

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out how to do it...

```
println ''
println String.format( "<b> List all JOBS having exclusions defined :</b>" )
println ''

for(item in jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(hudson.model.Job.class)) 
{
  if(item instanceof hudson.model.ExternalJob)
    continue   

  for(wrapper in item.getBuildWrappersList())
    if (wrapper instanceof org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.exclusion.IdAllocator)
      println item.name
}
```

To sum up......the changes that I did,I called the **getBuildWrappersList** to retrieve the Build Environment parameters.For my case,I was trying to find out which jobs were using the ArchiveArtifact plugin and display them for the user...

[Build Environment capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1sDF.png)

Cheers :)